# Unable to get query string in PHP (Beginner / Simple Question?)

Tags: php, file-upload, get, query-string

I keep it short. I have a file that can be uploaded to our server via PHP. Now, I want to rename that file based on the query string in the URL:
https://XXX.de/QG_002a.html?tic=undefined

In this case, I would want the file to be named "undefined".

Problem is, the upload works if I enter a filename manually, but it does not work if I try to grab the query string for it. Here is the code:

```
$actual_link =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts = parse_url($actual_link);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$newfilename = $target_dir . $query['tic'];

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir . 
$newfilename)) 
{
    echo "The file has been uploaded.";
}
```

I really googled a lot and tried many solutions for getting the current URL or getting the query string like:

```
$_GET['tic'];
```

But nothing works in my case. Could anyone please have a short look at the code? Maybe it's just a simple beginners mistake. Thanks a lot!

COMPLETE CURRENT PHP CODE

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {    

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir . $_GET['tic'];)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

CURRENT ERRORS

```
VM46 uploadForm_Gallery.js:355 POST https://XXX.de/upload.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
saveToQueue @   VM46 uploadForm_Gallery.js:355
(anonymous) @   VM46 uploadForm_Gallery.js:245
dispatch    @   VM44 jquery.min.js:3
q.handle    @   VM44 jquery.min.js:3
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const url = 'upload.php'
const request = new Request(url, {
method: 'POST',
body: formData
});

fetch(request)
```

Comment: That trick with `$_GET` is the correct way to do that. If it does not work, the problem might be elsewhere, e.g. wrong target dir? Any error messages?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I updated the post with the complete - small - PHP Code, the JavaScript POST command and the current error that pops up, if I use the $_GET method.

Comment: I'm confused, your URL in JS does not have `?tic=...` part. If it is in `formData`, then in PHP you must use `$_POST['tic']` instead of `$_GET['tic']`. Also, quoted error "500 (Internal Server Error)" just means your PHP script died miserably. You might want to go look at logs to see actual error message.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Could it be that I am misunderstanding something basic here.
Should I instead of  
const url = 'upload.php'
write
const url = 'upload.php' + ticID
?

ticID representing the "?" + the query string before fetching the request?

Comment: Well, you can write that and I think it should work, but make sure your PHP side works with `$_GET['tic']`.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you are a beginner in a coding language, even small steps can become campaigns. And the solution was so easy. Thanks again!